# Install extension hosted in Chrome Web Store without ugly inline modal

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, browser-extension, chrome-web-store

My client has an extension hosted in the Chrome Web Store, and is looking for a more frictionless install UX on her website than either 1) clicking out to the Chrome Web Store or 2) Chrome's [Inline Installation](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/inline_installation), which triggers an ugly modal that doesn't fit the aesthetic of her site.

Ideally she'd present the user with a button that matches her aesthetic, and the extension would install on click. A confirmation message would be fine as well - the goal is just to make install easier and cleaner for the user.

I found this link on installing [external extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/external_extensions), but the documentation is pretty arcane. Would these approaches deliver the desired UX on Windows and/or Mac computers? Any other ideas?

Comment: How is a "confirmation message" different from the "ugly modal"?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing it. :) But perhaps it's customizable?

Answer (score 3):

For consumer installations, the answer is no. [All extensions on Windows](http://chrome.blogspot.com/2014/05/protecting-chrome-users-from-malicious.html) must come from the Chrome Web Store, and that means going through the security-vetted installation flow of either Store or inline installation.